# How to fix TypeError in vue.js created hook?

Tags: vue.js

error:

```
vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: handlers[i].call is not a function"

found in

---> <StageExecs>
```

vue.js

```
<div id="vue-job">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>test</h3>
        <stage-execs></stage-execs>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    Vue.component('jobs', {
        delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
        props: ['job'],
        data: function() {
                return {
                    showExecs: false,
                    build_ids: []
                }
            },
        created: {
            stageExecs() {
                url = "api/v2/exec?" + this.job.api_url + "&limit=10"
                fetch(url)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(body => {
                        for(i=0; i<body.length; i++){
                            this.build_ids.push({
                                'id': JSON.stringify(body[i].build_id),
                            })
                        }
                    })
                    .catch( err => {
                        console.log('Error Fetching:', url, err);
                        return { 'failure': url, 'reason': err };
                    });
                }
        },
        template: `
        <ul id="example-1">
          <li v-for="item in build_ids">
            [[ item.url ]]
          </li>
        </ul>
        `,
    });


var v_root = new Vue({
    delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
    el: '#vue-job',
    data: {
        job_exec: {{ job_exec|safe }},

    }
});
```

I assume something is being called in the incorrect order here, but new to vue.js so not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: what's on line 597? Also, what's the code in StageExecs where the error is being reported from.

Comment: line 597 is in vue.js library itself - so no idea what that means

Comment: So you have your own file called vue.js as well?

Comment: The error is pointing to StageExec - so what's in that?

Comment: also I updated my code with the correct namespacing (you can see StageExecs now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is created() hook needs to be a method, not an object. See this working sandbox fix https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-e0dzj

```
created() {
    url = "api/v2/exec?" + this.job.api_url + "&limit=10"
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(body => {
            for(i=0; i<body.length; i++){
                this.build_ids.push({
                    'id': JSON.stringify(body[i].build_id),
                })
            }
        })
        .catch( err => {
            console.log('Error Fetching:', url, err);
            return { 'failure': url, 'reason': err };
        });
    }              
},
```

Comment: So that works but introduced a new error, I am going to create a new post for that.

Comment: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'api_url' of undefined"

Comment: Where did you define api_url? The "job" prop on the component should be passed an object that contains a property called api_url

Answer (score 0):

your `data` component should be an object, not a function, you replace it like below :

please check the doc as well : [Declarative-Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering)

```
 data: {
     return {
         showExecs: false,
         build_ids: []
      }
```

Comment: No that syntax is fine for a Vue Instance object - only component data needs to be returned. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Comment: @Trent the keyword function within data does not make sense there, it should be an object instead

Comment: Given he has set custom delimiters, my guess is he's trying to integrate vue into an existing handlebars (moustache) application, thus that value is being set out of scope. But it's still an object, and it's still OK. The error was the created() hook

Comment: @Tren yeap u are right we cannot declare a function within the created hook